# Trying to adapt Pre-Trained BERT to another use case of semantic separation of sentences

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

i have used huggingface BERT for sentence classification with very good results, but now i want to apply it to another use case. Below is the kind of dataset(not exact) i have in mind.

```
 set_df.head()
```

```
    sentence                                subject                   object
0   my big red dog has a big fat bone       my big red dog          big fat bone
1   The Queen of Spades lives in a Castle   The Queen of spades     lives in a castle
```

I have a train dataset with these three columns, and i want it to be able to bisect the test sentences into its constituents. i have looked into the different pre-trained models in BERT, but i havent  gotten any success. Am i using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better question is to refine how you are framing the task: If, in fact, the constituents are non-overlapping, this might be a case for [`BertForTokenClassification`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertfortokenclassification). Essentially, you are trying to predict the labels of *each individual token*, in your case either something like `no label`, `subject`, or `object`.

A great example for this kind of task is *Named Entity Recognition (NER)*, which is generally framed in a similar fashion. Specifically, HuggingFace's transformer repository has a [very extensive example](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/ner) available for you, that can serve as inspiration on how to format inputs, and how to train properly.

Comment: yes. I forgot to add that i had already tokenized the columns. i had not previously thought to think about it as a token classification problem. and yes the constituents are non-overlapping. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Since you are a new user, I want to point out that you can accept answers, if you have the feeling that this answer sufficiently solved your problem, see [help/asking]. This has the benefit of pointing future visitors to answers that *you* found helpful. I have to note that I am in this case "rewarded" with reputation.

Comment: I did accept your answer, but my reputation is too low for it to show right now. It will eventually.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're confusing upvoting with accepting, which is why I'm posting a link to this article as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/394422 Let me know if this is what you did already, just trying to get you started in the community as best as I can ;-)

Comment: I feel that your idea, while intuitive, leads me into complications with pandas and dataset formatting. Secondly, sentence level predictions and not token level because  The "subject" and "object" are semantically different from each other, even though they may share similar constituent words. How about i concatenate object and subject in one column, give them labels 1 and 0, and then train it.  That would give me a binary classifier.  That done, is it then possible to pass a new sentence through it, so that it can predict which part of the sentence is subject, and which part is object?

Comment: I  think this goes well beyond the scope of a single question, and should not be resolved in the comments of an answer anyways. I don't see a simple way of framing this differently, and you shouldn't feed in pandas to begin with...

Comment: I would like to move this discussion to chat so that i can get more clarity. And i will, as soon as i get one more reputation point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211407/discussion-between-kay-fresh-and-dennlinger).

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved this problem by modifying the data into a CONLL format, where each row contained only one word with the matching label subject\object.
my      subject
big     subject
red     suject
...     ....

Voila, It became a regular Entity recognition problem to be resolved using BERT for Token recognition. AS an extra piece of advice, I got it to work with Roberta but I needed to go through a complex de-tokenization process.